# Showing videostream in Tkinter, use full window

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv

I want to show the camera stream in a tkinter window, but I want it to use the whole window.

I use PIL.Image.resize() to resize the image to the size of the window, but that takes much time and if I move the camera fast, the frame rate goes down.

Is there faster possibility to resize the image or to make it using the whole window?

Here's my code. I mesure the time for each step:

```py
import cv2
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def main():

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.configure(width=500, height=300)
    window.config(background="#FFFFFF")

    lmain = tk.Label(window)
    lmain.place(relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
    threading.Thread(target = showFrame, args = {window, lmain}, daemon = True).start()
    
    window.mainloop()

def showFrame(window, lmain):
    while True:
        ti = time.time()
        _, frame = cap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        tim = time.time()
        size = getSize(window, img)
        img = img.resize(size)
        print('resize')
        print(time.time()-tim)
        print()
        tim = time.time()
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        print('Image -> PhotoImage')
        print(time.time()-tim)
        print()
        tim = time.time()
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        print('Set background')
        print(time.time()-tim)
        print()
        print('Total')
        print(time.time()-ti)
        print('---------------')
        print()
    
def getSize(window, img):
    wx = window.winfo_width()
    wy = window.winfo_height()
    imgSize = img.size[0] / img.size[1]
    if wx/wy > imgSize:
        x = round(imgSize * wy)
        y = wy
    else:
        x = wx
        y = round(wx/imgSize)
    return (x, y)
    
main()
```

Output:

````
0.05290079116821289

Image -> PhotoImage
0.018404722213745117

Set background
0.032300710678100586

Total
0.11109066009521484
---------------

resize
0.05290484428405762

Image -> PhotoImage
0.01847553253173828

Set background
0.03982210159301758

Total
0.11800694465637207```
````

Comment: Look at [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) and [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#filters). `.resize()` uses `BICUBIC` by default. Try changing that to `NEAREST`. I think it will run fast enough if you use `NEAREST`